# Para que serve variáveis do tipo Int32Rect

Tags: c#, .net, processamento-de-imagens

Baixei um projeto que trabalha com imagens e em alguns casos ele utiliza variáveis desse tipo, não entendi qual a finalidade desse tipo de variável no processamento de imagens.

Comment: Você já deu uma olhada na documentação dessa `struct`, [Int32Rect Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.int32rect(v=vs.110).aspx)? É apenas uma estruturada para armazenar alguns dados de posicionamento e tamanho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Int32Rect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.int32rect(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma estrutura de dados que expressa um retângulo cuja altura, largura, origem X e origem Y são todos inteiros de 32 bits ([`Int32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Pode ser usado, por exemplo, para [delimitar uma área retangular numa seleção de imagem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602486(v=vs.110).aspx), para [escrever dados em um *Bitmap*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346816(v=vs.110).aspx), passando até mesmo [por aplicações de jogos](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5Xaho68xOTsC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=int32rect+applications&source=bl&ots=2pVY3LjIJc&sig=kfLWoSn05Pzig9tMaqxVYB99xl8&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8_9Tyh6PJAhWNqZAKHYoYDRoQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=int32rect%20applications&f=false). As aplicações são várias.